# run EF6 async request in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have mvc 5 and EF6 and never really use async in mvc before so want ask best way for run sql requests.

```
public ActionResult SearchTest(string id)
{
    string searchtxt = UsefulClass.ConvertObjectToString(id).Replace(",", " ").Trim();

    var model = new SearchResult();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchtxt))
    {

        //get the data from 3 requests
        var ArtistList = _db.Artists.SqlQuery("SELECT top 6 * FROM Artists WHERE CONTAINS(Name, N'Queen') and TopTracksStatus = 1 and GrabStatus > 1 order by playcount desc").ToList();
        var tracks = _db.Database.SqlQuery<TrackInfo>("exec SearchTracks @SearchText=N'Queen', @TopCount=10,@LengthCount=100").ToList();
        var TagsList = _db.Tags.Where(x => x.TagName.Contains(searchtxt)).Take(5).ToList();

        //work with ArtistList and add to model
        if (ArtistList.Any())
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var artist in ArtistList)
            {
                i++;
                if (i == 1) //top artist
                {
                    model.BestArtist = artist;
                    model.BestArtistTrackCount = _db.TopTracks.Count(x => x.Artist_Id == artist.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    model.ArtistList = ArtistList.Where(x => x.Id != model.BestArtist.Id);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //work with tracks and add to model
        if (tracks.Any())
        {
            model.TopTrackList = tracks;
        }

        //work with tags and add to model
        if (TagsList.Any())
        {
            model.TagList = TagsList;
        }

    }
        return View(model);
}
```

Here I have 3 requests which return ArtistList, tracks, TagsList and I need add them to model and then pass to view. How to do it in async way?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/data/jj819165.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try below example, hope it gives you a good idea.

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> SearchTestAsync(string id)
    {
        string searchtxt = UsefulClass.ConvertObjectToString(id).Replace(",", " ").Trim();
        var model = new SearchResult();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchtxt))
        {
            var art = GetArtistListResulst(model);
            var track = GetTracksResults(model);
            var tag = GetTagsListResults(model,searchtxt);
            await Task.WhenAll(art, track, tag);
        }
        return View(model);
    }


    private Task GetArtistListResulst(SearchResult model)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var artistList = _db.Artists.SqlQuery("SELECT top 6 * FROM Artists WHERE CONTAINS(Name, N'Queen') and TopTracksStatus = 1 and GrabStatus > 1 order by playcount desc").ToList();
            // You don't need to use foreach because the artistList is ordered by playcount already. 
            model.BestArtist = artistList.Take(1);
            model.BestArtistTrackCount = _db.TopTracks.Count(x => x.Artist_Id == model.BestArtist.Id);
            model.ArtistList = artistList.Where(x => x.Id != model.BestArtist.Id);
        });
    }

    private Task GetTracksResults(SearchResult model)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            model.TopTrackList = _db.Database.SqlQuery<TrackInfo>("exec SearchTracks @SearchText=N'Queen', @TopCount=10,@LengthCount=100").ToList();
        });
    }

    private Task GetTagsListResults(SearchResult model, string searchtxt)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            model.TagsList = _db.Tags.Where(x => x.TagName.Contains(searchtxt)).Take(5).ToList();
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am afraid there is no point in creating a Task for that. The idea is to make IIS to wait for an IO completion port, so if you spawn a task, you are still blocking a thread. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/data/jj819165.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some people said what making sql requests in separate task was necessary for EF5, but this is not best way for EF6 because we have ToListAsync() which already return the Task, but there are problem what it make error if run more then one async request on one DbContext. So I am not sure if use Task.Run() best way.

Comment: hi @Duke, sorry for the delay. What I'm showing you is call Parallel async. 
When you have more than one I/O bind implementation like querying from DB, and 
both of  implementation are not dependent on each other, Parallel async is very efficient, 
because in your case you have multiple queries for your models. I used Parallel async. 
And from your comment like "somebody said...", I can tell you that's not true. Different cases need to use 
different approaches. You can learn more about aysnc at below link:  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907